# When reading a NDEF tag the content it's showed in "NFC service" instead of the app

Tags: android, nfc

I'm trying to read a NDEF tag from my app in Android using ADT.

The code it's exactly the same as the one found in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um5iF.png) tutorial.

The content it's showed correctly but, instead of opening my app, it's showed in a clone of my app (same UI) that it's called "NFC service" with a bluetooth icon.

The problem is: if I already opened the app then, after the reading, it clone itself and everything I do after the reading it's done on the "NFC service" clone.

This is what the multitask menu shows:

[image]

where "Servizio NFC" translate, as said, in "NFC service"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't comment on the issue that the app is shown as "NFC service" with a Bluetooth icon in the history -- that obviously looks like a bug.

However, if you want your app to receive NFC events while it already is in the foreground, I strongly recommend to use the [foreground dispatch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch) or the [reader mode API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#enableReaderMode%28android.app.Activity,%20android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) (reader mode is new in Android 4.4).

In order to use the foreground dispatch, you would create a pending intent like this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this,
    0,
    new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
    0);
```

Then, in your activity's `onResume()` method, you would enable the foreground dispatch like this:

```
NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null);
```

Note, that you could define intent filters or tag technology lists and pass them to the `enableForegroundDispatch()` method if you don't want your activity to receive **every** discovered tag.

You will then receive intents notifying you about discovered tags through the activity's `onNewIntent()` method:

```
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    ...
}
```

Remember that you **have to** disable the foreground dispatch in your activity's `onPause()` method:

```
NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
```

Comment: I added the `onResume()` method (I hadn't one before) with the `PendingIntent` as you said and now works. Honestly I don't have any idea why but it could have been worse.