# App called "NFC services" replacing my own app

Tags: android, android-intent, titanium, nfc

I want my Android app to start after scanning an NFC tag, so to make some tests I modified the tiapp.xml of Favebooks (a simple tutorial app for Titanium) by adding the following lines:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<manifest>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true"/>
    <application android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium">
        <activity
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="Favebooks"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:name=".FavebooksActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
                <data android:host="test.it" android:scheme="https"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
</android>
```

Unfortunately, another APP called "Nfc service", which looks exactly like Favebooks, starts instead of it after scanning a tag. I have tried every launchMode available to no avail. What am I doing wrong? [Here's a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ8bW.png)

**EDIT**

For simplicity's sake, let's put this in index.js.

```
Ti.API.info('Launch Intent ' + Ti.App.Android.launchIntent.getData());

var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    layout : 'vertical',
    height : 'auto'
});

var text = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    name : 'test',
    hintText : 'test'
});
win.add(text);

win.open();
```

Now let's try start the app by approaching our device to a tag. It does so correctly:

[INFO] : TiRootActivity: (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity resume. activity = com.Test.app.TestActivity@42a0df48
[INFO] : Launch Intent https://test.com

Bit if we press the home button, click on the app icon and go check our logs we can see than the activity id of what just started is different. So for example anything that we had written in the text field got lost. I don't want this to happen.

[INFO] : TiRootActivity: (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity create, savedInstanceState: null
[INFO] : Launch Intent null
[INFO] : TiRootActivity: (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity resume. activity = com.Test.app.TestActivity@42cb8370

Comment: can you post your nfc code? Also, is that screenshot you manually opening the activity and then nfc-ing the activity?

Comment: That screenshot is me starting the app by clicking on its icon, then on the home button and then scanning a tag.  What do you mean by NFC code?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question would be to replace this line of code `android:launchMode="singleTop"` by this one: `android:launchMode="singleTask"`.

I posted an answer to the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908103/android-app-name-is-not-displayed-in-the-multitasking-screen/36313826#36313826).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What you see is actually *your* app. Your app being displayed as "Nfc Service" (possily with a different icon) *in the recent apps history* seems to be a bug(?) in Android (or certain Android versions???).

Also see this question: [When reading a NDEF tag the content it's showed in “NFC service” instead of the app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23657981/2425802).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I have understood that the cause was android:name=".FavebooksActivity", if I deleted the name of activity, there was not a replacing of the app. I hope this can help you.