# Android App name is not displayed in the multitasking screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, nfc, multitasking

I've developed a simple NFC application that reads and displays the data(NDEF Records) present in the NFC tag. I modified the Manifest file so that whenever a tag gets tapped, my app gets opened.

Now the problem is when I manually open the app and check the multitasking screen, it displays my app name i.e NFCReader but when the app gets opened itself when a tag comes in contact with the device, my app gets opened but when I check the multitasking screen, it doesn't display my app name. Instead it displays NFC Service. What should I do to overcome this issue?

Comment: This seems to be a known issue: [When reading a NDEF tag the content it's showed in “NFC service” instead of the app](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23657981/2425802)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have set your activity declaration, in your manifest, to something like this:

```
<activity
     android:name=".packagename.MainActivity"
     android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
     android:launchMode="singleTask"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Main">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <data
             android:host="domain.com"
             android:scheme="http" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I think the answer to your question is the following line of code that you forgot to add: 
`android:launchMode="singleTask"`

I invite you to read about launch modes [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) and [here](https://www.mobomo.com/2011/06/android-understanding-activity-launchmode/).

**Please note:** This answer is based on the use of [Reader mode API](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#enableReaderMode%28android.app.Activity,%20android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29), otherwise check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23659052/5432092).

Hope this helps!