# Prevent Unity from opening other service app (NFC Service)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nfc

I an creating an NFC Reader in Unity. I just need to read a text from a NFC tag.
Everything is working fine but when I read the NFC tag, another app "NFC service" is opening and the text is showing inside this app instead of my Unity app.
I need to stay inside my unity app and even if I force quit NFC service, it open again.
I am on android 6 and android 7.
I use the plugin : Android NFC from asset store to read NFC.
Thanks.

Comment: Seems like this may be a Samsung Galaxy issue? https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/help/seriously-how-kill-nfc-service-t1747701 It mighthelp if you'd provide some information about the phone, android version, SDK version, etc...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/23657981/2425802, is this what you are experiencing?

Comment: Hi, thanks.
The problem is that I can't modify system files because it's for a customer application. I can't do this trick on thousand phones.